# C++ Array Loop questions still need assistance

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok this is a difficult question to google. What I want is once a user enters 10 items in the inventory array I want it to clear the console and tell a story. I tried but it would display the story no matter how many items were in the array as I defined the array as max 10. Also Im trying to find a way to SWAP an item in the array. what I mean by this is I want the console to ask the user if they would like to trade {item which is already in the array} for {item2}    y or n?

Problem is it doesnt display the items name just the position in the array, whe outputted in the story example. "would you like to trade1for enchanted sword" is displayed. Then if you hit yes it doesnt add it to the array. Also it bypasses my thank you anyways

```
  void tellStory(InventoryRecord list[], int& size)
{
    int numOfRecs = size;
    int pos = rand()%numOfRecs; //Generate a random position of the item
    //Generate item to trade, I'll refer to it as "Item
    int TRADE_CHANCE = 0;
    const string str = "Enchanted Sword";
    InventoryRecord recList[MAX_SIZE];
    if (numOfRecs == MAX_SIZE) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "So your ready to begin your quest!" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Before you begin I would like the opportunity to trade you a rare item!" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to trade" << pos <<  "for" << str  << "?" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Yes or No? ";
        cin >> choice;
      if (toupper(choice) == 'Y') 
    (rand()%100 < TRADE_CHANCE); 
   (recList[pos], str);//Here add the trading stuff, which is some text, user input(y/n) and replacing realist[pos] = Item, etc
     }
     else {
         cout << "Thanks anyways!" << endl << endl;
   system("pause");
  }
  system("cls");
    }
```

Comment: holy crap that is a lot of code in one post.  what do you want us to do?  maybe cut down to only the relevant section...

Comment: It's better to provide a very small example that demonstrates your problem instead of dumping your whole code here.

Comment: the code isnt needed I figured it might help what I am trying to do. What I want is in the beginning of the post. I dont know how to swap an item in an array and how to do a loop once array reaches a certain size

Comment: Just a comment to using `system`. While it isn't wrong to use it, you should be aware that it is not a simple function call to an internal function but a call to an external command of the system. `system("pause")` can for example be replaced with [`cin.ignore();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)[`cin.get();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

Comment: Thanks I forgot to switch over to the cin.

Answer (score 3):

Thing is you aren't checking anywhere for the inventory to be full. You may want to replace

case 'A': addData(recList, numOfRecs); break;

If you want to tell a story only once

```
case 'A':
    if (numOfRecs == MAX_SIZE-1) {
      addData(recList, numOfRecs);
      //TELL STROY HERE 
    } else{
      addData(recList, numOfRecs);//If you want to tell a story only once
    }
    break;
```

If you want to tell the story anytime

```
case 'T': //TEll story
    if (numOfRecs == MAX_SIZE) {
      //TELL STORY HERE 
    } 
break;
```

OR, even though it will be annoying,  after every action, check if 10 items are in inventory and display the story

Now for the trading, assuming you want them to trade an item they have, for a random item you are gonna generate use:
    pos = rand()%numOfRecs; //Generate a random position of the item
Now if you want to generate a "random" suggestion for trade:

```
if (rand()%100 < TRADE_CHANCE) {
    int pos = rand()%numOfRecs; //Generate a random position of the item
    //Generate item to trade, I'll refer to it as "Item"
    SuggestTrade(recList[pos], Item);//Here add the trading stuff, which is some text, user input(y/n) and replacing realist[pos] = Item, etc
}
```

If the item you want to Trade, its actually a position swap in the same array:

```
int pos = rand()%numOfRecs; //Generate a random position of the item
int pos2;
do {
    pos2 = rand()%numOfRecs; //Generate a random position of the item
}while (pos2 == pos);
//Actually "swapping"
InventoryRecord tmp = recList[pos];
recList[pos] = recList[pos2];
recList[pos2] = tmp;
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: I did the case A I ran into a issue, it doesnt run the story. if I try to enter the 11th item it does my error msg. I will try case T to see if I like it. I cant believe I didnt think of that. Although I want it to be auto matic as soon as the 10th item is added to the array I want it to tell the story.

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses this is helping alot

Comment: I've explained there how to make it automatic, even with a chance, you can set trade chance to 99, or remove the conditional, and there you go. Also, there is a way to only show the story only once(by once i mean 10th element, remove element, 10th element again(no story this second time), which is, set a bool to false, outside the loop, before everything, and when you reach the 10th item check if the bool is set to false, if it is tell the story and set the boolean to true.
BTW if this helped you, try accepting it as answer, or at least vote it up xD!

Comment: Ok, so I decided to do the case T. How do I make the menu disappear when it tells story via case T? I tried the system 'cls' but it didnt work. As for upvoting I cant I dont have enough rep yet apparently. But I will mark as the answer

Comment: If cls ain't working, you could try some workarounds, like print certain number of blank lines. I would suggest using ncurses, but that would be too much. Remember C++ doesn't handle the concept of "console", and cls is a non standard system dependant solution.

Comment: Ok I figured out the cls